# give local pid and node name, how to convert to remote pid?

Tags: erlang

A remote pid registers its `"local pid"` and `"its node"` name has been registered into `mnesia` table. If another node's pid fetch the above `"local pid<0.xxx.xxx>"` and node name, how to convert to `remote pid<xxx.xxx.xxx>`.

Comment: If a process is locally registered on the node, couldn't you just do:  rpc:call('node@remote-host', erlang, whereis, [localpid]) to retrieve the remote pid?

Comment: The parameter of whereis is regname, not localpid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really see **WHY** you have to do anything special at all. Here I will create a mnesia table running on `l@renat` and `r@renat` and write and read pids from the respective nodes and show their is no need to "convert" the pid as Erlang's distribution mechanism **automatically** take care of it. It will be a bit long to get it all working.

First on node `l@renat` we connect or the other node and create our mnesia schema:

```
Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
(l@renat)1> net_adm:ping(r@renat). 
pong
(l@renat)3> mnesia:create_schema([node()|nodes()]).
ok
(l@renat)5> mnesia:start().
ok
```

On node `r@renat` we have just started mnesia:

```
Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
(r@renat)1> mnesia:start().
ok
```

On node `l@renat` we then create a table and insert an entry containing a local (to `l@renat`) pid:

```
(l@renat)6> mnesia:create_table(local, [{attributes,[node,pid]},{ram_copies,[node()|nodes()]}]).
{atomic,ok}
(l@renat)8> mnesia:transaction(fun () -> mnesia:write({local,node(),self()}) end).
{atomic,ok}
```

Note that I have not defined the records but am explicitly reading/writing the record tuples. You can do that, but it is best to use records. Now on node `r@renat` we can read the same record:

```
(r@renat)10> {atomic,[Lr]} = mnesia:transaction(fun () -> mnesia:read(local, l@renat) end).
{atomic,[{local,l@renat,<5893.37.0>}]}
(r@renat)11> node(element(3, Lr)).
l@renat
(r@renat)12> mnesia:transaction(fun () -> mnesia:write({local,node(),self()}) end).
{atomic,ok}
```

and we see that the pid refers to a process on another node(), node `l@renat`. We have then added a record to the table containing a local (to `r@renat`) pid. If we then read that record on node `l@renat` we see that it contains a pid of a process on node `r@renat`:

```
(l@renat)13> {atomic,[Rp]} = mnesia:transaction(fun () -> mnesia:read(local, r@renat) end).
{atomic,[{local,r@renat,<6007.85.0>}]}
(l@renat)14> node(element(3,Rp)).
r@renat
```

So we see that a "conversion" is not necessary.

In fact any form of "conversion" is in fact totally meaningless. A pid refers to a specific process on a specific node so trying to convert it has no meaning. It is an atomic data type. And even if you could convert it you have no idea of what process it would actually refer to, if any.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand the "automatic conversion" now.